# Função javascript que chama outra função javascript dentro de um while

Tags: javascript, funções, while

Estou com um problema ao executar uma função javascript que em seu escopo possui um while que de acordo como o contador é incrementado, é chamada uma segunda função javascript passando como parâmetro o valor do contador:

```
function funcaoA(){
    var cont = 1;
    while (cont != 'p'){
        if (document.getElementById(cont+'_campo') != null){
            funcaoB(cont, 'tipo_do_campo');
            cont++;
        } else {
            cont = 'p';
        }
        alert('mensagem');
    }
}
```

Ao executar esse código, a mensagem solicitada é executada mas a funcaoB() dentro do while não executa.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Uma hora a variável `cont` é numérica, outra é *string*, isto obviamente não vai dar certo. O que você deseja fazer? Dê informações relevantes para resolver o problema, se possível coloque um exemplo funcional. Como tem certeza que a função não é executada? Como estão os elementos no HTML?

Comment: A funcaoB é uma função de verificação, o usuário digita uma informação no campo e ela retorna se essa informação está cadastrada no banco. Caso verdadeiro, ela bloqueia o botão ao lado do campo para adicionar a informação ao BD, caso falso, ela deixa o botão livre para inclusão dos dados no BD.
No caso a funcaoA faz a inclusão dos dados no BD e executa novamente a funcaoB para que ao ser fechada a janela pop-up o botão de inclusão de dados esteja bloqueado.

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer `while (cont > 0)`, `else cont = 0;`? do que converter de numérico para string.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, sua função esta ok, caso você queira verificar campos `1_campo`, `2_campo` ..., Especifique melhor o problema.

Comment: No caso o while é executado até que se tenha verificado quantos campos há no documento. Os campos são nomeados da seguinte forma: 1_campo, 2_campo... Eles podem ser acrescentados ou removidos, de acordo com a quantidade de informação a ser salva de uma só vez, por isso que cont recebe 'p', ou seja até que existir campos ele vai chamar funcaoB, quando ele chamar document.getElementById(cont+'_campo') e for igual a null o cont recebe p e finaliza.

Comment: Você esta falando... **A funcaoB é uma função de verificação, o usuário digita uma informação no campo e ela retorna se essa informação está cadastrada no banco**, você vai em um banco de dados para verificar isso? por que não faz logo tudo do lado do servidor?

Comment: Sim, ela pega o que está digitado no campo e busca no banco de dados se aquela informação já está cadastrada

Comment: Pode ser um monte de coisa, e parece que o problema está na função B. Pode postar o código dela?

Comment: O problema não está na função B, pois, executo ela para verificar os dados inseridos e ela funciona normalmente, o problema é quando ela é chamada pela função A. Se executada somente uma vez, funciona, mas da segunda interação em diante deixa de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

executei a função aqui e funcionou normalmente, ja verificou se os campos do documento estão com o id corretos (1_campo, 2_campo)? talvez assim ficasse melhor pois evitaria a conversão do tipo da variavel....

```js
function funcaoB(a, b) {
  alert("faz alguma coisa com " + a + " e " + b)
}

function funcaoA() {
  var cont = 1;
  while (document.getElementById(cont + '_campo')) {
    funcaoB(cont, 'tipo_do_campo');
    cont++;
    alert('mensagem');
  }
}
```

Comment: Em partes funcionou, mas só quando é inserido os dados no último campo que o botão dos campos anteriores são bloqueados

Answer (score 0):

Nathan, acredito que você deve está encontrando algum problema com o escopo das variaveis, entre tente fazer as seguintes alterações.

tente utilizar alguma forma mais estruturada para agrupar os seus elemetos, seja usando um `namespace`, uma `class`, um `data-custom`

Como o seu codigo já usa algo semelhante a um namespace, então vou postar um exemplo utilizando namespace:

```js
var campos = document.querySelectorAll("[id|='campo']");

[].forEach.call(campos, function (campo, indice) {
  console.log(campo, indice);
});
```

```html
<input id="campo-1" type="text" />
<input id="campo-2" type="text" />
<input id="campo-3" type="text" />
<input id="campo-4" type="text" />
<input id="campo-5" type="text" />
<input id="campo-6" type="text" />
<input id="campos" type="text" />
```

o selector `[campo|='namespace']`, vai pegar todos os elementos cujo o valor do campo selecionado (no caso `id`) possuam o `namespace` informado, ou seja começam com uma determinada `string` seguinda de um `hifen`, por isto no exemplo acima o `input#campos` não é capturado pelo seletor.

como você está passando o seu `cont` para a `funcaoB`, acredito que você esteja refazendo a consulta (`getElementById`), então aconselho que passe o `input#campo-n`.

```js
var campos = document.querySelectorAll("[id|='campo']");
var funcaoB = function (campo, indice) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(campo.id, campo.type);
  }, (indice + 1) * 1000)
};

[].forEach.call(campos, function (campo, indice) {
  funcaoB(campo, indice);
});
```

```html
<input id="campo-1" type="text" />
<input id="campo-2" type="number" />
<input id="campo-3" type="date" />
<input id="campo-4" type="time" />
<input id="campo-5" type="email" />
<input id="campo-6" type="tel" />
<input id="campos" type="text" />
```

note que no exemplo acima, mesmo fazendo uso do `window.setTimeout` para simular uma requisição `AJAX`, não tive problemas em pegar o `id` e o `type` de cada `input`.

em todo caso fica dificil lhe ajudar sem ver o script todo, afinal o seu problema possivelmente está ma `funcaoB`